# Why do some instructors care so much about attendance?

Tags: attendance

It seems that in higher education, some instructors either do not care at all whether students attend, and others care minimally (often resulting in a 1-5% attendance grade or tie-breaker rule).

However there are also many instructors who seem to feel very, very strongly about attendance, and take it upon themselves to enforce this in various ways.

For instance, I was shocked by a [recent question claiming that 15% of the grade would be lost](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/65857/244) for missing 2 lectures - according to the question author, the class meets so frequently that this would constitute missing less than 3% of the lectures! While this seems like an extreme case, it seems like it's not uncommon to find professors who may deduct 10% or so for missing a small fraction of lectures.

Why are these professors so preoccupied with making students attend? If attendance is so crucial to doing well in the class, wouldn't the students who don't attend do poorly in the exams anyway? Why additionally punish those students who did not attend, but did well regardless?

Comment: Students who don't attend but still do well challenge the professor's EGO.

Comment: @BenVoigt; As in my answer, I think a bigger problem is students who don't attend because they *think* they can still do well, but turn out to be mistaken.  This challenges the institution's retention rate.

Comment: "If attendance is so crucial to doing well in the class, wouldn't the students who don't attend do poorly in the exams anyway? " - Yes. And so an "attendance required" policy is at least [mildly effective](http://www.ccsu.edu/retentionandgraduation/files/attendance.pdf) at reducing absences and increasing pass rates, which is something many instructors consider desirable. (Especially in e.g. the context of a community college, vs an elite institution.)

Comment: Different subjects are different. In the question you link to, the class described meets 5 days a week, which may mean that it's a language class.

Comment: "Professors *ego*": totally off - I do not mind if students are away from my class, although I work hard to make it informative and interesting. However, I *do* mind if students complain about difficulty of material, bad marks, etc. and they haven't attended. They have been forgoing some essential component of the course, and it's someone's else fault?

Comment: It's just another way to trouble the students.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs  -- I don't even care too much about the bad marks and griping.  I care more if the habitually absent show up to office hours asking for an explanation for something they would understand if they went to class.

Comment: @BenVoigt It has little to do with the instructor's ego and more to do with students that don't bother attending lecture and show up in the office hours immediately prior to an exam expecting the prof to spoon-feed the material to them.

Comment: "*If attendance is so crucial to doing well in the class, wouldn't the students who don't attend do poorly in the exams anyway?*" Maybe, maybe not. There are some things that can't be measured well on exams, and if the professor makes an effort to teach those things in class, what else can they do?

Comment: @BenV - In the (hopefully extreme) case of the brilliant student who is unfortunately stuck in the lecture hall of a mediocre professor who does little more than read the bullets off his slides or parrot the book, you may have a point. However, when I see empty chairs in my classroom, more often than not, the absent students are lazy idlers rather than savants. They rarely crack open the book they paid good money for, and don't seem to mind forfeiting the education they are paying for, either, for the sake of a little extra sleep or a bit more video game time. Egos run in both directions.

Comment: @ff524 This makes less sense now with lecture recordings available. I used to listen to recordings only and did well in many subjects despite not attending a single class physically for those subjects.

Comment: There was a relevant question at [Professor only teaches what is already in textbook. Should I quit going to the lectures?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13363/professor-only-teaches-what-is-already-in-textbook-should-i-quit-going-to-the-l/) which may provide some insight.

Comment: @J.R.: Sure, and I do not mean to suggest that all professors who care about attendance are doing so for egotistical reasons.  Merely the ones who do so by explicitly reducing the course grade for absence, when there are [so many better ways to engage students and get them into class](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/57619/8705).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: By your own statement "I do not mind if students are away from my class" you are not in the group of professors my comment concerns.

Comment: In our experience here it is very unlikely for any student who regularly attends the lecture to fail the exam, even if they are not putting more effort into it. Just a case of "subliminal learning" I guess. I survived two lectures I did not like by doing the exercise sheets for one of them while passively listening to the other. I passed both, without having the feeling that I put extra effort in either.

Comment: FWIW, at my (German) CS-department, there is not a single course with forced attendance. (Exercise sessions are different sometimes, if rarely.) This is a question of (learning) culture: do you expect your students to be mature enough (before or after they graduate)?

Comment: @Raphael there's a lot of grade inflation in the U.S., and you're right that the "weeder" courses (one in econ, one in engineering computer science) I took didn't check attendance at all. Perhaps there's an inverse relationship.

Comment: That 3% figure is closer to 5% if one takes into account schools that are based on the quarter system. Also if the student was taking a foreign language class, I can understand that kind of requirement.  Students who take a beginner level foreign language class because they already know that particular language are wasting everybody's time. It's a good idea to dissuade such students from taking your course in the first place (even if by the end of the course, you don't end up enforcing the lowering of their grade).

Comment: And finally, a foreign language is also a good example of a subject where you can do very well during the final written exam, but be absolutely horrible when it comes to understanding and conversing in that particular language. Another good example is a physical education class. When I took a course on resistance training (weight lifting), the course had such a long waiting list of students wanting to get in, it made sense that the instructor wanted to dissuade the students who took that class less seriously from wanting to enroll in it.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the stricter the attendance rule the more worthless the class.

Comment: I don't take attendance, but it really chaps me when a student doesn't come to class and then expects me to reteach 4 weeks of material to them in office hours. That's a no from me dawg.

Comment: I don't take attendance. Unfortunately, students who want to drop my course after the official deadline need my permission, and on that web form I have to say when the student last participated in the class. Sometimes I can make a good guess on the basis of homework or exams, but other times I (briefly) wish I had taken attendance.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

One theory is that it serves as additional motivation for students to attend class, which in turn helps increase their success in the course.  It gives them a short-term incentive to do something which is hopefully also in their long-term best interest.

> If attendance is so crucial to doing well in the class, wouldn't the students who don't attend do poorly in the exams anyway?

In many cases the instructor has found from experience that this is true.  But the student (who has less experience) may not be as convinced.

Consider a student who wakes up in the morning and doesn't feel like going to class.  In a class with no explicit attendance requirement, the student may rationalize: "I will just study harder tomorrow to learn the material that I missed, and I'll still be able to do well on the exam, so skipping class will have no consequences."  But they overestimate their ability to do that, and end up not learning it as well.  Or tomorrow they put off the studying until the next day, and so on, and fall behind.  As an eventual result, they do not do well on the exam.

In a class with an attendance requirement, the student knows *for sure* that not attending class will have negative consequences.  The biggest consequence (failing the exam) is very likely but not guaranteed, and the student may not be able to impartially evaluate just how likely it is.  But loss of attendance points is guaranteed.  So the student cannot pretend that skipping class is harmless.  Thus the student is more likely to actually attend, which is in their long-term best interest anyway.

Hopefully, the ultimate result is that a higher percentage of students are able to meet the standards of the class.  The flip side is that some students who have good attendance but poor performance otherwise may get better grades than they "deserve", but the instructor may feel that this tradeoff is justified.

Comment: You don't need to penalize poor attendance explicitly, you just need to make the explanation clear.  Putting something in the syllabus about "There are no points assigned to attendance, because there don't need to be.  Exam scores always reveal those who skip class." might get the message across even more convincingly.  Also, the student in the other class is getting 91% on exams despite blowing through the professor's missed class limit, and on my calendars, the semester's only half over.  So clearly attendance isn't so essential as the professor is thinking.

Comment: In the end, you could also give easy points for attendance (which will get most students coming to class) without harming those who ARE able to learn in other ways, by including attendance in an overall grade, but giving the option of using the final exam score as the final course grade instead of the overall grade.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If you say "always" then every student will know this is a lie.  Obviously there are students who never attend and do fine on exams.  If you say "usually" then it is quite possible that an improbable number of students will think they can be the exceptions.  See [the Dunning-Krueger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Comment: @BenVoigt: In my opinion, giving the option of using the final exam as the final course grade is a HUGE Dunning-Krueger trap.  Students can say "I'm smart, why waste my time going to class?  I'll just study in the last week and do great on the final, and then none of the other stuff I missed will matter."  And more often than not, they'll be wrong.

Comment: For those, there should be the opportunity to test out.  I've met a bare handful of people who would bet on the exam only after being out of school; all my classmates would rather have taken the easier points throughout the semester than have that much riding on the final (especially on a comprehensive final); however the final-replaces-all provides a last chance at redemption and takes away any chance to complain about homeworks being too long or attendance being worth too much.

Comment: And honestly, Dunning-Kruger should only be a factor for students who haven't met prerequisites, and the professor does a disservice to the other students if he tailors the course for those lacking the groundwork.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Your views differ from my experience in a number of respects.  But ultimately this comment thread isn't the place for a thorough debate, and I am afraid we may just have to agree to disagree.  Feel free to have the last word.

Comment: I'll just close by saying that I think other methods for encouraging attendance (covered in some very interesting questions on this site) such as making lectures more interesting, more audience participation, etc. are much better than marking off points for absences.

Comment: It's hard for students to know how good your lectures are if they don't show up, though. :-)

Comment: Should the teacher really care about how well his "barely-students" perform? If you want to give a warning, make a test early on. If you don't, well... the student can just take the class (or semester, or year...) again. Either they learn from their mistake, or they don't. I'm just thinking of how much time and effort is wasted rearing people who should already be adults, in theory. Sure, it is an extra incentive - but is it really worth it?

Comment: @Luaan: It's a fair philosophical question: is the purpose of a university to deliver education only to those already strongly motivated to participate in it, or is it appropriate to encourage or gently coerce participation by students who might not do so on their own?  I'll just say that in US academia, the rates of retention and timely graduation are generally viewed as an important measure of quality for an institution.  Thus if a student doesn't pass a class, it reflects poorly on the student but also on the institution, program, and instructor.

Comment: @Luaan: When evaluating instructors, institutions definitely look at the rate at which students pass or fail their courses.  Therefore, yes, instructors do have an incentive to care about how well all students perform, even those you might classify as "barely students".  (Of course, there are competing incentives to maintain academic standards.)  You could argue that such incentives should not exist, but the fact is that they do.

Comment: That's a great point if we assume a private educational system (just for simplicity, not politics). On one side, people want to buy education at an institution that has a high retention rate and short graduation period. On the other side, companies want people with quality education as cheap as possible. Within the quality constraints, retention and short education are a benefit for both parties, and quality becomes a balancing act between making things easier and attracting enough students, and giving companies enough value for their money when hiring your graduate. Business as any other.

Comment: This is a non-reason assuming you want to educate mature, self-regulated learners. If class attendance is essential, we have to trust and require that students will figure that out. Extrinsic pressure does not help the long game.

Comment: Even though these are terrible reasons, I think this is probably the rationale that a lot of professors use, so +1 for that.

Comment: Great answer. The idea that the point of classes is to satisfy the requirements is a damaging and pervasive one. The point of classes is to help the students learn (yes, this is hard to define exactly). Tests, projects, attendance policies, and other requirements are there to help motivate students to learn. The instructor's job is to decide which requirements to impose, based on his or her experience, but all are fair game.

Comment: Given how much education costs at least in the US (both public and private), wouldn't you say anyone enrolled in a US university is already strongly motivated ipso facto?

Comment: Also, I selected this answer because I think it most directly addresses the misapprehension in my question: That students can be trusted to act rationally with regards to attendance, and that forcing students to attend regardless whether they think it's necessary CAN ultimately be beneficial.

Comment: Lots of people in this thread assuming that the point of taking a class is to pass the exam, rather than to gain the education on offer in the class, where the exam is just one of the means this education is provided.

Comment: This is coddling and, in this case, detrimental to learning, itself, which is not limited to course material. Yes, it's true that it can potentially hurt student retention rates for universities. If, however, students don't learn to create their own fail safes and always expect some organization to do it for them; this in no way fosters academic independence.

Answer (score 91):

Let me start off by saying that it is very unlikely that attendance requirement is purely to protect the professor's ego, as one comment suggested. Any serious educator would understand that the goal of education is not so that the students become increasingly reliant upon the education system. Rather, the goal is to produce students that are increasingly independent, critical, and confident in their own reasoning. If I were a professor, I would be glad that the student can succeed without my help, rather than the other way around. To punish a student for being able to succeed without the help of lectures is simply contradictory to the goal of education.

With that being said, here are some more plausible reasons:

1. The class is discussion based. This is quite straightforward: if you
   don't attend the class, then you do not learn. The in-class learning
   experience cannot be compensated by self-study, and exams may not be
   an ideal measure of such experience.
2. The class meets very infrequently. There are certain classes that meet only once per week. Missing one class means missing a significant amount of work. A related example is science lab requirement. In my undergrad institute missing one lab (without advanced notice) means that you automatically fail the class.
3. The lectures contain information not otherwise (easily) available. This is more relevant for higher-level classes, where there are no standard textbook and the way the professor teaches the material may be unique. The professor may want to make sure that students attend lectures to get the information they need.
4. Culture. In some culture regular attendance is associated with deference to the system and/or the lecturer.

One finally note: contrary to what OP stated in the question, it is my personal experience (in the US) that very few professors would deduct a significant amount of points due to a lack of attendance. Instead the focus, if there is any, is usually on participation of class activity (which, of course, can only be fulfilled if you attend the class). What OP have described seems like rare exceptions rather than the rule.

Comment: Regarding 4: Is there a culture where class attendance in university is almost always enforced? I also thought that one might view the class grade as a measure of not just knowledge but also discipline. However this cannot be the case if there is no way to look at one's transcript and tell which A's are "attendance withstanding" and which are "in spite of [in]attendance".

Comment: @Superbest This seems to be an example: http://baylorlariat.com/2013/12/03/editorial-attendance-policies-can-be-too-strict/

Comment: Also to #1, if you don't come to class, you may be injuring your classmates' learning experience, so a punitive penalty is apt.  In the extreme, consider a performance/studio class like theater, choir, or band, but the idea applies for foreign language as well and many courses that use flipped classroom instructional strategies.  If only half the band shows up, what's the point of even having class?  @Superbest at my undergrad, you could tell the difference. A, B, C, D, or F you attended.  An FA (Failure due to absences — 2 weeks missed) you didn't attend.

Comment: Is there a difference between "Stroking Someone's Ego" and "Deference"?

Comment: @Aron: there is a difference. Stroking someone's ego is purely personal to them, whereas deference acknowledges the standing of the university as a whole, by ostentatiously showing respect to its representatives, the faculty members. Showing deference *usually* has the effect of stroking the egos of those same people, but it additionally has a purpose to do with the whole institution (and perhaps wider structures/hierarchies: consult your local sociologist for details!).

Comment: @SteveJessop sounds like you are saying one is stroking your professor and the other is stroking a building. Other than that everything else seems to be window dressing.

Comment: @Aron: if you like, but anyway that is sufficient difference to constitute a different motive in the minds of the people whose "preoccupations" the question is about. Perhaps they are less reductionist than you about what a "university" actually is (they think it is not only a building), but even if they're wrong about what a university is, "my students should ostentatiously show respect for the institution" is different from (albeit in some cases a superset of) "my students should ostentatiously show respect to me".

Comment: @guifa: This may well be true in the cases you describe, but in many others the opposite is true: a student who does not want to attend the class, forced to attend it, might impair the learning (and teaching!) experience for everyone else, by being disruptive or otherwise just uninterested in the class.

Comment: @tomasz generally, peer pressure takes care of that.  I can honestly say that while I've had many a student not show up and fail, not do group projects, not hand in assignments — that is, the whole gamut of non-participation—, I've only once ever had someone actively disrupt my classroom (and it was so severe, security had to be called).  Students who attend are normally peer-pressured into participating, but attendance is really just a proxy. If non participatory but present, they should be similarly downgraded

Comment: @guifa: I'm not talking about severe, active disruption. Even merely sitting there with a dead stare, or reading a book can be bad, as they make it hard to get feedback. Peer pressure won't likely prevent people from quietly talking (I don't think it should), but if you force people to attend, they are more likely to spend lectures talking about completely unrelated matters (including with students who would have paid more attention otherwise).

Comment: @guifa: Varies by institution? Where I am I had active "saboteurs" (disruptive, snide comments, making fun of other students for asking sincere questions, calling security for removal) maybe once a semester as long as I allegedly held the attendance requirement. Once I released that, the problem almost entirely went away (literally).

Comment: I'd add #5) "they track because they are being tracked"? They get graded too... low attendance reflects badly? And #6) Rumuneration. Aren't some schools remunerated based on head count... low headcount affects the balance sheets.

Comment: These are all non-reasons assuming you want to educate mature, self-regulated learners. If class attendance is essential, we have to trust and require that students will figure that out. Extrinsic pressure does not help the long game.

Comment: @Raphael, I'm not sure if your assumption holds.  Some see their role as _more_ than just educating a student on the particular subject.   Whether this is considered valid or invalid, I cannot find much fault in a Professor who wants to help his students _become_ mature and self-regulating.

Comment: @MichaelJ. Sure, I'm all for that. But forcing them *will (on average) not do that*. They will yield to the pressure, of course, but release it and they will go back to before. You have to allow them to fail first and then learn -- that's only human. (I'm fully aware that most education systems do not incentivize allowing failure. That's part of the problem.) And yes, we tried that.

Comment: Points 1-3 seem irrelevant if the student actually learns or already knows the content. #1 would be relevant if it harmed other students; #2 if this was the only way of demonstrating to the teacher that you knew the content (as opposed to having a final exam or handing in reports).

Comment: @raphael *citation needed*

Comment: @Jeff Personal experience. I'm quite sure there's a study somewhere, though. (I can summarily recommend the work by Linda Nilson.)

Comment: It has been my experience that only two types of classes ever assign a significant amount of points to attendance.  Classes that can easily be passed without attending. ( ie Music 101 )  where test are multiple choice straight from assigned reading.  Or classes that are so difficult, professors are willing to do anything to keep from failing 95% of students or where they have to pass at least 40% on curve and they prefer that 40% actually know something.  My general rule when at college was to immediately drop any class with an attendance policy that wasn't of the later type.

Comment: You said "...the goal is to produce students that are increasingly independent, critical, and confident in their own reasoning."  While true at one time, in the era of microaggressions, safe spaces, trigger warnings, speech codes, and censorship, it doesn't seem to be the goal these days. Today it seems to be "Think as independently as you would like but you have to agree with us on thousands of issues without giving it any critical thought or open discourse at all.  If you to dare think differently than we do, you will be shunned, targeted, harassed, bullied, mocked, insulted and expelled."

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga If the already know the content, then why are they taking the class in the first place?

Comment: @IanSudbery I don't know. Could be a required credit or something?

Answer (score 45):

So here are some observations from my perspective: I teach at a large, urban, community college. We are open admissions (no starting prerequisites) and the students have many challenges (graduation rate 15-20% in the university at large; ~25% for our own college). I'm very much an outlier in that I'm one of the few faculty who *don't* want to be tracking attendance closely. I'm constantly trying to understand why other faculty are so adamant about this; and frankly I have yet to receive a super-coherent account of it. But some bits and pieces that I get at times:

- Students may be so weak that they are subject to the Dunning-Kruger effect; they have no idea how in trouble they are, or what it takes to remediate their weaknesses. Perhaps they are not in a position to make a rational choice about their academics, and at this point need some enforced guidance in that regard, esp. in a linked-knowledge STEM discipline. (To me, this is the strongest argument, the one that allows me to at least entertain the thought once in a while.)
- There may be a legacy/cultural aspect; for example, at our school we are given paper rosters with calendars marked out on them for each class, with the direction to mark it a certain way for attendance every day. I've never seen a contractual/handbook requirement that we do this, but the paperwork says so, and they are required documents to be filed at the end of the semester.
- There may be institutional reporting metrics at stake. For example, if a student misses 4 classes (course meets twice a week), then the college lets us drop them from the course, and my department quasi-mandates that we do so. I think part of the reason is that the student then counts as an "unannounced withdrawal", which makes our "failure" statistics look better (to very high-pressure stakeholders higher up in the university administration).
- Some instructors may do this to make the course *easier*. I've heard at least once that an instructor in another department had, say, a 70% grade component based on attendance. That is: a student is not required to perform any work whatsoever; as long as they are physically present, they can pass the class (and thus relieve some amount of pressure on the instructor, I presume).
- "Remember, the attendance rosters are legal documents. Years ago there was a student accused of a crime. They were proven innocent because of their being marked in class that day, which counted as an alibi." (I've heard this lore multiple times.)
- "Attendance is important to reporting for financial aid; we must confirm that students are attending for certain financial aid requirements." (About 75% of our students get federal/state grants?)
- "Don't you think attendance is important? Don't you want students to succeed?"

Comment: "`I've heard this lore multiple times.`"  Allow me to dispell some of the ambiguity, so this might possibly be a bit more traceable.  I've had college president Ron Price tell his faculty, in a faculty meeting that I attended (as a member of his faculty), that he experienced that at his school.  I believe he said he did so at the Lancaster (California) location of Charter College, so that would have placed the event at November 2010 - May 2012.  (I'm not suggesting that this is the only case where a student was crafty enough to accomplish this technique, but am providing about just 1 instance)

Comment: @TOOGAM: Hmm. When I've heard it, the implication has been at our institution (and also further back then those years?). To me it has the scent of urban myth. At any rate, it seems like a highly suspect/inefficient reason for documenting class attendance every day (i.e., taking time out of class to be parole-officers-in-waiting).

Comment: **Any college granting 70%(!!) grade component based on attendance should instantly lose its accreditation**. What was the name of that institution and department please? It's basically farming us the taxpayer and rewarding warm bodies with a pass for showing up. (Would it graduate a chicken which passed the course? if not, on what basis? I would enroll my chicken and appeal, just to prove the point.)

Comment: @smci (I'm guessing your comment is based on the 4th bullet point, not my comment which provides such details.)  Before jumping to that conclusion so quickly, I think it prudent to consider: what course is it?  I remember taking some classes ("physical education", choir, maybe drama, maybe "college study skills" where key criteria involved things like in-class performance and demonstrations of positive attitude.  I wouldn't want to blindly instantly remove accreditation for an entire college without knowing more details.

Comment: @smci e.g., [Whatcom Community College](http://whatcom.ctc.edu), "Preparation for the SAT" course, CMSVC 085T -- as I recall, getting a "Pass" only required attending something like 3 out of 7 classes.  At the start of class 2, they took attendance, and then said (to all those who were present), "If you were here last week, the only thing you're required to do, to pass, is to attend one class out of the next 5 weeks."  This is an old example (Spring 1995), but I just present it as an example of the diversity of requirements that can exist.  Use those requested institution/dept names as desired

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I wouldn't call the case I'm citing as an "urban myth"; at least not from my perspective, because the person who gave me the info (whom I cited for you) was directly involved.  So this isn't one of those myths that completely lacks any reasonable amount of trace-ability.

Comment: @TOOGAM but he clearly said '70% for **attendance**' not 'for **participation**'. 'Attendance' simply means showing up: whether sober/high/sleepy/unprepared. If he really meant 'for participation' he should have said that, I agree there are a few courses where that could be justifiable.

Comment: "Students may be so weak that they are subject to the Dunning-Kruger effect" would you mind editorializing that less? Humans are not weak when psychology facts are true and apply to them. If you dispute the effect then by all means, make that claim directly.

Comment: @djechlin: I mean academically weak, as in "unskilled" and "incompetent" per the language of Dunning-Kruger's papers: [link](http://psycnet.apa.org/?&fa=main.doiLanding&doi=10.1037/0022-3514.77.6.1121), [link](http://cdp.sagepub.com/content/12/3/83.abstract)

Comment: Disambiguate language? I don't think the overall answer/paragraph is in a technical enough register linguistically speaking that "weak in the specific domain" is implied.

Comment: @djechlin That's not some super technical term. If you perform poorly in an area, then you're weak in that area. There's nothing to criticize here.

Comment: @DCShannon totally agree, so say "weak in that area".

Comment: @djechlin He pretty much did. They're weak in the area of being students, so they are weak students.

Comment: @DCShannon he "pretty much" slipped a weasel word in. Anyway I downvoted, apparently I was the only one bothered enough to downvote an otherwise OK answer over this. Life goes on.

Comment: @djechlin, I think this is completely unambiguous, the thought that this might have used the (as I consider it, archaic) meaning of weak as in "of weak character" didn't occur to me, and re-reading it I still can't see how anyone could come to that conclusion: "Weak student" is a phrase every academic I know uses weekly.

Answer (score 23):

The following isn't a general answer, but it is one good reason for grading based on attendance in a wide variety of courses. There is [extensive evidence](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2014/05/08/1319030111) that active learning is significantly better than lecturing, at the 95% confidence level, in essentially all STEM fields, as measured by success rate or normalized gain.

If you're doing active learning, you need your students to show up on time and prepared for class. It's not like a lecture. If you're lecturing, and a student slips in 20 minutes late and quietly sits down in the back of the room, that student is only hurting him/herself. If you're doing active learning, then the student is disrupting the whole process, and will likely need to be brought up to speed by their peers on what is going on.

There is a similar issue if you have students who have not been making any effort to keep up with the course. If you're doing active learning techniques, those students are holding back the rest of the class. For example, if you're doing think-pair-share, the student has nothing to contribute, so the "pair" part doesn't work at all.

So if you're doing active learning, you can't just make vague threats to your students that if they flake out, they'll fail the final.

Personally, I don't have an explicit attendance grade, but attendance is required, and the way I enforce that is by giving an easy 5-minute multiple-choice reading quiz at the beginning of every class. This is a technique advocated by [Mazur](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0135654416), for use with flipped classroom techniques. It enforces the requirement that students actually do the reading before coming to class, which is a requirement for a flipped classroom to work.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times. In most of the classes I teach, students DO WORK IN CLASS, not uncommonly in groups. Sometimes there is no way to substitute individual work or homework (like, how does individually project managing even make sense?). So yeah, if you're not there you're not actually learning what I'm teaching.

Comment: Quibble: The "active learning" findings are not an either/or affair. The Freeman article points this out at the end: "Is more always better? Although the time devoted to active learning was highly variable in the studies analyzed here, ranging from just 10–15% of class time being devoted to clicker questions to lecture-free 'studio' environments, we were not able to evaluate the relationship between the intensity (or type) of active learning and student performance, due to lack of data..."

Comment: If you don't have an attendance grade, but just have in-class activities, then I don't think you're in the same situation the asker is asking about. You're grading actually doing something, participation, not attendance.

Comment: I gave a flipped course (<10 students) last term without forced attendance. Without forced anything, really. I tried my best to engage the students in ways they would see help them, and make them come back. Attendance was high (aside from sickness and scheduling issues, I'm not aware of any missed sessions), the number of hand-ins low. The students performed between A+ and B+ so far. What I learned: if you offer something, they come. (In this case, the material was hard and the session the single point where they could get help.)

Comment: @Raphael: Interesting. Are you at a school with selective admissions?

Comment: @DCShannon: The distinction between grading for participation or performance and grading for attendance is often blurry in practice. The reading quizzes I give are so easy that they're essentially free points for showing up.

Comment: @BenCrowell No. It was an elective course, though. Most attendees were not specializing our track.

Answer (score 22):

> Why are these professors so preoccupied with making students attend? If attendance is so crucial to doing well in the class, wouldn't the students who don't attend do poorly in the exams anyway?

I am an instructor who sometimes makes attendance or participation part of the grade.  There are several reasons for this (many of which already appear in other answers).  The main ones are:

- I'm at a large state school where most of my students are under-prepared for the class academically (these are math classes and officially meeting the prereqs is very different from knowing the prereqs), and need all the instructional help they can get.
- Most of the students are taking the class as a requirement, not because they want to be there.  In addition, many of the students are not super responsible, and benefit from psychological incentives to attend class and keep up with the material.  (The Dunning-Kruger effect is also a concern here.)
- The material is cumulative so getting behind makes it harder to catch up, especially for weak students.
- We face a lot of pressure from the university to ensure most students do not do poorly in their classes.  In effect, we are blamed for not keeping our students on track.  It's not a matter of, "it's the students' problem, not mine" if they don't pass.
- The complete content of a 15-week course cannot be assessed in a few hours of exams throughout the semester.  I want my students to learn and understand more than what's on the exams.

> Why additionally punish those students who did not attend, but did well regardless?

The point is not to punish students who did not attend, but to motivate students to attend to give them opportunities to do well in class.  In my experience, very few students who skip most classes do well on the exams.  Personally, I don't usually make attendance worth a lot (except in classes where in-class work/discussion is a crucial part of the class) and I make my grading policy flexible, so I can bump people up for doing well on the final exam, say.  This way, poor attendance, or doing poorly at the beginning of the course does not ruin the student's final grade.

Comment: In other words, your job is giving students tools, not tests - it's worth very little if they pass the tests but learn to use no new tools. That said, would you allow a student to be absent if he demonstrated sufficient skill in advance?

Comment: @Luaan Probably---in practice, students don't ask.  Anyway, my attendance policies are not so draconian as in the other question.  Usually you get 1 attendance point per class, so missing a couple classes is no big deal.  (OTOH, if the student knows everything in the class before hand, they are in the wrong class.)

Comment: Those are also great points :) Though with some classes, we had no option to have a class accepted without actually taking the class - ithose were exceptions, though.

Comment: Great explanation. Dunning Kruger is recurrent theme here, and indeed, nobody would care about good students who can pass with excellent grades without attending. However, most *think* they can, while the reality is exactly the opposite.

Comment: Just my 2 cents from being a student at a CSU. I don't know what subject/level of classes you teach, but from my experience, the only classes I was ever required to go to for attendance were for GE's. And as a high performing student being forced to attend lecture was very annoying, as I really had no need to be there. Thus I would simply read, play games on my phone/computer, watch videos, or do homework for other classes at the back of the class. You can force me to be there, but don't expect me to like it, and if you try to force me to pay attention, don't expect that to go well.

Comment: That last point doesn't get enough attention. Too many students -- and a surprising number of commentators on this site -- think passing an exam implies one has mastery of a subject. I really can't fathom how anyone who's experienced higher education can believe that.

Comment: Completely agree (I am a lecturer also). Very good students will do well *in spite of my performance*, and bad students will have bad results *no matter what I do*. What I have to try to do is that all the others students (who are normally the majority) do well. And for them, attendance requirements **do** help, even when they think they won't. (And by the way, @ChrisWhite comment should be printed big and set in the banner of the site).

Answer (score 15):

Disclosure: I am a lecturer, and I do care about attendance, however I have only limited experience. I don't enforce attendance, because I don't have leverage to do so (at least not in a way that would not upset students to the point which will hurt my chances further career). But I would very like to follow the example of the professor you mention.

There are several reasons, why the lecturers care about the attendance.

1) Dunning-Kruger effect. Often many students, who are enrolled in a class, are totally unaware of difficulty of a course, appear at introductory class (which is usually less difficult) and start skipping others. Then they start getting a clue in the middle of the semester, when they appear at the lectures, and their only experience is that they do not understand anything (so, then they deduce, the lecturer has to be responsible, since they should understand anything and any time). Because of that experience, they then skip the rest of the lectures and get a blow when they are unable to solve a single task in an exam. Finally, more often than not, they still think that it is not their fault, and if the university grades their staff based on students' feedback, it really becomes a problem of a lecturer.

So, forcing them to start attending at the beginning of the semester may avoid this problem.

2) Insufficient support of the university for keeping the standards from sinking to the bottom. Nobody would care about Dunning Kruger, if a lecturer could flunk everyone who does not satisfy the minimum standard at the test. At many universities you probably cannot grade 80% of the class negative, and then expect to retain your position. Sad but true. It is probably worse in for-profit institutions. So if there is some minimum, yet unspoken target of how many students should be graded with positive grades, then a lecturer will try to ensure that at least this many actually attend the lectures and have chance to pass the exam, so the lecturer can fulfill HIS unofficial quota of how many students must pass.

Not much to do with ego, but a lot to do with experience. Really no problem for me if people do not attend and do well, but then it means that they did not need to take the class anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Well, the simple correct answer is probably this: answers vary.  There are multiple instructors, and with them there may be multiple reasons.

When I was a college instructor, I was told that the college had made certain promises about what the college would do, which included having students physically on the premises for a certain number of hours.  Students who did not show up were hurting the percentages that the college needed to keep high in order to fulfill its obligations.

**Edit:** *adding this paragraph*, since I suspect this might not be easily implied by everyone.  Checking attendance and following up with non-attenders, even of a single class session, may be an ***expected requirement*** of the job.  For me, they were.  Class sessions were 4+ hours long each, and instructors were even expected to try calling students' cell phones during the first class break, if they didn't attend.  Different instructors, like many types of employees, had different levels of how much they may have fulfilled an individual requirement.  Still, this simply demonstrates that "pressure from above"/administration may be one reason that may influence some instructors.  Attendance was not directly graded (due to some government-related regulation), but there were requirements about how attendance would negatively impact grades under the category of *class participation*, and attendance could also affect the final grade by impacting additional grade percentages such as in-class quizzes.  Some details may have been simply encouraged at some times, while being requirements at other times, and the simple way to be compliant was to just be strict (resulting in this being a significant requirement on students).  Even in an institution that doesn't have as strictly enforced policies, there may still be requirements, or suggestions (which might be received as requirements), that might have influence on some instructors.  (These influences may come from a certain college president, or department head.)  Such influence might impact many years down the road, even after the instructor is no longer under the same supervisor.

Another reason is that students who don't show up are, well, not attending.  This means that they are basically one step away from dropping out.  (The only step away from being a drop out is not what they do, but how often they are doing it.)

Another reason is that a key purpose of the college education system is to provide the students with the preparation that they will be needing.  As I've read this site, I've learned more and more that the precise goals may vary a bit between different institutions, particularly those that describe themselves as "research institutions" vs. those that describe themselves as "career preparation"/"technical colleges".  Maybe some have some more philosophical/altruistic goals rather than corporate culture.  Regardless, an element that is likely to be quite common is to want people to be successful in the organizations that they join after college.  Most organizations do not want people to be failing to meet attendance requirements.  If students can be exposed to a certain level of expected discipline, such as an official demand of attendance, that may result in certain character building that may serve them well after graduation.

Some argue that final exams would have their grades harmed by students who aren't learning, and so we can just rely on the final exams as a useful, accurate way of measuring knowledge.  The counter-argument is that a student who skips classes may be a good test taker, and may effectively manage to demonstrate knowledge, while not managing to successfully demonstrate the discipline of needing to meet requirements other than just knowledge.  Some employers don't treat the diploma only as a demonstration of accumulated knowledge and understanding of related principles.  Instead, they treat the diploma as a demonstration of students being able to meet whatever requirements were placed on the student, which may involve some life skills (like scheduling) and not just accumulating certain pieces of "head knowledge".  The educational institutions (or individual faculty members within educational institutions) may be choosing to cooperate with such methods.

Again, I refer back to my initial paragraph.  These are simply some reasons, and one or more of them might be part or all of the reasoning that gets used by some instructors, while other instructors may have their own different reasons.  So consider these various arguments as just being a sample, and not as the single clear-cut absolutely-right universal answer that everyone, everywhere, is actually using.

Answer (score 9):

One reason for requiring attendance is for international student visa eligibility.

In the United States, students on F-1 or M-1 student visas must maintain [full-time student status](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/maintaining-your-status) in order to stay "in status", i.e. keep their visas valid. Note the emphasis below on **attending classes**, **passing classes**, and taking **a full course of study** (i.e. being a full-time student taking a normal semester's worth of credit hours).

> While studying in the United States, both F and M students must:
>
> - Attend and pass all your classes. If school is too difficult, speak with your DSO [designated school official] immediately.
> - If you believe that you will be unable to complete your program by the end date listed on your Form I-20, talk with your DSO about requesting a possible program extension.
> - You must take a full course of study each term; if you cannot study full-time, contact your DSO immediately.
> - Do not drop a class without first speaking with your DSO.

Comment: In the UK, if the university takes on some responsibility to ensure they are in attendance, it is easier for them to sponsor students for their visa.

Comment: You can just sign their paper no matter whether they attended. (Which is technically not okay, but a common solution around bureaucratic BS.)

Comment: It's not usually wise to play games with la migra / State Department / Homeland Security bureaucracies in the US. They go after people who they think disrespect them.

Answer (score 5):

Particularly in the early years of university, students are overwhelmed by the freedom of university compared to high school. They can be late, skip classes, even miss the odd assignment, and nobody will take them aside and scold them for it. On top of that, there are parties somewhere every day, and a wealth of social events.

Many people who were A students in high school get overwhelmed by the change in university, and end up not succeeding.

Some professors want to ease this transition, by taking away an element of choice, or at least reminding students that there's a reason to go to class, even if it's not mandatory.

Sure, there are students who will succeed without going to class, and students who will fail even if they do go to class. But many professors weigh this, and see it as worthwhile to "waste" class on these people, which has really very little harm, if it results in others succeeding where they otherwise would not.

At the end of the day, it is very unlikely that someone will fail because they attended class, but far more likely they will fail because they did not.

Comment: "which has really very little harm" -- actively wasting time of your best students, maybe even annoying them to the point of disliking the material is "little harm"? I disagree.

Comment: @Raphael It's not a waste of their time. Even the best students will still learn in class. Furthermore, in an active learning environment, they will be able to help others learn, which is a win for everyone. The strong student will get stronger by answering questions from others, and finding different ways of explaining the same concept. Plus, sometimes the way material is presented in class is not the same as the book, and the strong student who misses class would have no idea how to fill in that resulting gap in knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of answers here about ensuring that students don't fail, that professors are adhering to university strictures, or that professors don't want to be inundated with idiotic questions from students who skipped class and then ask basic questions that were covered. All of those have merit and may be true, but they are not the reason that I assign a high proportion of my course grade to attendance and participation.

I am an assistant professor at an R1 in the USA. I teach political science. Attendance and participation are weighted very heavily in my class because one of the core skills I focus on teaching is critical thinking. I don't give tests or quizzes. Rather, students are graded on their in-class participation (which demonstrates mastery of the assigned readings and the ability to engage the ideas in those readings) and several written assignments designed to prepare students for policy-oriented jobs "in the real world."

Moreover, while I understand that some people view college courses as simply a means to an end, that is neither my philosophy in teaching nor my goal in providing a class. To my view, class meetings are precisely when the *real learning and work gets done*. I organize my class so that midterm and final written assignments are an application of the knowledge and skills we covered in class. It is the exchange of ideas in real-time between students and professor that I care about the most. A student who wants to simply write some assignments and submit them without coming to my class misunderstands completely the purpose of my class.

When people treat class attendance as a nuisance, they overlook the important epistemological benefits of being in a classroom setting where questions can be asked in real-time and students can challenge one another and the professor. There's a dynamic element that is lost. This may be different in other fields - I wouldn't know.

Comment: How do you grade in-class participation when university classes often have hundreds of students in them? Do you just mark tutorial/practical participation, since they're smaller classes of 20-30 students?

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no-one went for the "pedagogic high ground" answer: that in some cases, the published intended learning outcomes, either at institutional, programme, or module level, include one or more outcomes for which an attendance check is a valid (albeit perhaps incomplete) assessment.  For example, there are a [bunch of institutions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22institutional+learning+outcomes%22+%22punctual%22&btnK=Google+Search&source=hp&ei=5JaBYIXHHa-blwTl2qugCg&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYIGk9MHMbWaVE5aUEMLV9ffpPu3ED8_K) where the institutional learning outcomes include being punctual; and any engineering programme whose programme learning outcomes are based on the [UK-SPEC](http://www.engc.org.uk/engcdocuments/internet/Website/UK-SPEC%20third%20edition%20(1).pdf) Chartered Engineer Standard will include among them something like "Reinforce team commitment to professional standards" and something like "Create, maintain and enhance productive working relationships".

Answer (score 2):

I used to be an assistant professor, and occasionally would have an attendance requirement. The reasons for having such a requirement are as follow:

1. Students whose attendance is paid for by the military must attend
   lectures.
2. Student athletes must attend lectures to maintain their eligibility, and if applicable scholarships.
3. In full courses, students who don't attend are dropped so students who can attend may join the course.
4. The course has a heavy group-work or active component that requires the student to be present. In such a course, a student who chooses not to attend may hurt the educational outcomes of their classmates.
5. In some cases the student may not be prepared to take the course, for whatever reason, and should drop as soon as possible. If I track their attendance I may have been able to suggest to them that they should drop in time to get at least a partial tuition refund.

Students who do not come to class, for whatever reason, have poorer educational outcomes on average than students who do come to class. Frankly, it's in the interest of a student to come to the class they've paid for.

On a strictly personal note, I don't care to be a convenient excuse. Students who habitually skip class tend to blame their instructors for poor grades, even though their grades are poorer in large part because they pissed away the opportunity that they, or someone else, paid for.

Comment: Regarding 1 (and 2 which is very similar): Doesn't the military have a better way of tracking that, other than hoping a professor will decide to take attendance? Or do you mean that it is specifically the military that compels you (through university management) to have the attendance policy? In that case, do they ask you to track attendance only for the military students, or did the university reach "everyone has to attend" as a compromise to avoid special treatment for them?

Comment: @Superbest When I was teaching I was routinely queried about military and athletic students. However, in the interest of fair handed treatment I treated all my students the same where reasonable. Depending on the school, and in some cases, the state attendance tracking may be mandatory. There are also issues for public institutions wanting to be sure that the resources they expend on higher education are well spent.  In answer to your question, the military demands that the university track attendance through some sort of process that demands the instructor take attendance.

Comment: That's interesting know, I didn't think they were strict about that. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You give valid reasons for *tracking* attendance and reacting with reporting resp. reorganizations to absent students. However, I fail to see how they support making attendance mandatory for passing.

Comment: At the end of the day if students do poorly, it comes back on the instructor. The fact of the matter is that the average student who shows derives greater benefit from the course. Since the instructor's job is to help the students learn, getting the students to class is part of it. Making it beneficial in a grade sense to attend may motivate people to get to class. Finally, some states require attendance to be part of the grading scheme since the state expects the people benefitting from tax dollars to actually go to class.

Answer (score 2):

In Poland, almost 90% professors I've met required attendance on their class (only 2 lectures can be missed and only with good excuse).

I think the main reason behind this behavior was that they often presented expanded material (that wasn't included on the slides or docs) which was required on exams. Some of the professors doesn't provide any materials at all, so without own notes (or copies from others) You just don't have any sources of knowledge to learn from.

Very often lecture topics was really difficult and there was even no sources to learn from in the Internet.

Comment: You give a good reason why forced attendance is unnecessary as long as you make the facts clear from the start.

Answer (score 2):

- A. Some profs are evaluated by their management by student
  performance.  Non-attendance is not good for performance.
- B.1. Most all profs are rightly annoyed by students who ask questions
  about topics covered in the missed class.  This wastes the prof's as
  well as the other students' time.
- B.2. as in B.1, but during the prof's office hours.  It wastes the
  prof's time as well as other students waiting outside the prof's
  office.  15% seems a bit severe, but whatever it takes to get
  recalcitrant students to put on some clothes to get to class...

Answer (score 2):

Some instructors do actually care very much about attendance. Others may seem to, but I don't know that they have a **personal belief** in the importance of attendance as much as they intend to **follow the rules** set by various college administrators.

While the following too-long story is very much anecdotal, I would like to suggest with the moral to this story that while many instructors are "preoccupied with making students attend," they do not themselves "feel very, very strongly about attendance" despite presenting a front that suggests that they do feel this way. With so many good answers already I'd normally just pass this question by, and this approach is somewhat strange I admit (downvote bait?), but this issue has some personal importance to me.

> When I began co-teaching as a graduate student, our English department
> had a rule that missing more than three classes would result in
> automatic failure in that class. The English department was the only
> department with this rule in place from what I understand.
>
> I had studied English as an undergraduate student at the same
> university, and the rule had been explained to me in every English
> course I had, at least on the syllabus and often vociferously by the instructor. I missed more than three
> classes a few times, and would receive warnings, and wouldn't miss any
> more, but also wouldn't get kicked.
>
> One of the two professors that I "co-taught" under, who showed me the
> ropes in the beginning, was new to the university and the policy, and
> I always thought that he was somewhat iron-fisted due to the fact that
> he failed several students for missing a 4th day. It bothered me, but
> I didn't say anything at the time because I had a rather cowardly
> mortal terror of any direct superior at that point in my life and had
> been warned by professors as an undergrad that one is very much
> supposed to enforce the three-absences-or-less attendance rule.
>
> The next semester, as I began teaching on my own, we ran into each
> other and he said:
>
> **Why didn't you tell me that nobody actually enforces the attendance
> rule?!**
>
> When he was enforcing the rule in the presence of the violators he seemed
> adamant, even angry, and he seemed to think he was justified in enforcing it; he acted the part of the stereotypical lawful-good paladin, not sadistic but self-righteous. I thought that he
> actually felt "very, very strongly about attendance" as you put it.
>
> He
> didn't; he was just enforcing policies put in place by administrators
> who didn't care about the life-wrecking consequences of policies they themselves wouldn't have to explain face-to-face, who hadn't
> even made exceptions for classes that met three times a week vs. two. And he did so with an expression on his face that brooked no argument, but apparently not because he was actually angry; it was a stony, defensive expression, expecting hostility and confrontation.
>
> I taught my final two semesters on my own, and I didn't bother anyone
> about attendance, ever, and aside from a few students who failed
> themselves out of college through other means everyone kept showing
> up, even without the threat of the giant stick of doom.

Answer (score 1):

At least here in Switzerland there's one more reason (nobody mentioned yet...). The attendance is part of the credits you get for the course. Each point equals roughly 30 hours of work. Some courses have only small exams, then the actual attendance is an important part of these 30 hours. If you don't show up, you didn't do the work expected for that certain number of credit points.

However, I don't care that much as a TA here. Only people regularly being absent are reported. Generally I think they're old enough to know, how to pass their exams.

Comment: This either begs the question or has been covered a lot already, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: Being there is not per se work (on that course), so this thinking is clearly broken. (Their fault, of course, not yours.)

Comment: @Raphael : I would rather contradict here: You are supposed to be working along like asking questions, discussing, taking notes, etc. Some courses are even evaluated based on your notes (by e.g. writing a journal about what you learnt there). Attending a class is work in my eyes.

Comment: You're *supposed* to, yes. In any case, workload by credit represents all kinds of work, some of them attendance and some of them not. Checking some parts and not others is weird. In the end, the credits say, "this student passed that course which we think takes the average student so many hours to pass with an average grade" (at least that's the EU definition) but not "this student spend this many hours on that topic".

Comment: @Raphael : That's absolutely correct. I was always a student who had a very easy time learning my material. So in average I probably worked less than 15 hours for 1 credit (sometimes far less than that) while others had a really hard time making it at all. But the theoretical background is: The attendance is part of the workload for the credits, so you simply have to be there to get those credits.

Comment: @PatricHartmann I second this. In the EU-wide system of grading (not sure whether Switzerland is a part of the system) the credits are given for a) attending b) doing your homework c) taking the exam. A lot of professors do not take this seriously, since the students would be upset (they expect that if you take exam you are done), but actually the credit system was designed in that way.

Comment: @xmp125a : To an extend, though very confined, it also brings a certain fairness back to the system. Attendance is possible for everyone, whether a good learner or not. However, there is still much to be done outside the lectures where the actual imbalance of the system lies.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it's just about making our lives easier. If you never come to class, we expect you'll eventually have a panicking moment where you realize you're far behind, and you need personal help from us to get back on track. Everyone can avoid this unfortunate situation if we just make attendance mandatory. On the other hand, actually keeping track of attendance is a huge hassle, so some of us would prefer not to manage all that. I personally don't take attendance, but I do feel sad when students don't attend. I just don't feel it's my place to police and penalize adult behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is mostly in mathematics, where there often aren't (even at the undergrad level) regular problem sets or exams. Professors want some indication that a student has covered and understood the material, and classroom attendance is a decent proxy for it. I've never run into a math or science class (as opposed to humanities ones as an undergrad) that formally had an attendance component, but it's not like students could skip literally every lecture and still expect an A. I've seen professors try other method of grading with varying degrees of success: having students rotate in writing up and distributing notes to the class, having students do a bit of research and give a brief presentation at the end of the class on a related topic, etc. After a point, though, students are assumed to be there because they want to be there, and they're responsible for handling their own education.

That having been said, as a student, I never found classroom lectures particularly helpful. (I'm distinguishing ordinary lecture-based classes room things like colloquia or random topics classes, which don't have textbooks and are designed to be more participatory). I learned better from textbooks or papers, rarely had questions to ask the professor during the classes themselves (whether because I had more involved questions to ask over email or because I could work out the answer myself), and didn't enjoy the classes (as opposed to the material in them).

Comment: *My experience is mostly in mathematics, where there often aren't (even at the undergrad level) regular problem sets or exams.* Really? That's very different from my experience in the US. What country are you in?

Comment: @BenCrowell: Also in the US. Your profile lists your area of expertise as nuclear physics. I'm not a physicist myself, but the physics I has studied (mostly high-energy particle physics) did have regular problem sets at every level, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: Your experience is definitely... anomalous. I've never heard of that situation (no regular problem sets or exams) in any U.S. undergraduate math program.

Comment: " indication that a student has covered and understood the material, and classroom attendance is a decent proxy for it" -- not at all! Being there and doing something completely unrelated to the course is incredibly common. If you want to test coverage and understanding, you have to explicitly test for that.